# Activity no es llamada en Android

Tags: android-studio

Mi código llama a una activity dentro de una función, para recibir información del usuario (a través de algunas variables públicas):
.
... instrucciones
.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, confirmar.class);
startActivity(i);
.
... instrucciones que procesan datos recibidos de activity confirmar
.
```

.

El problema es que la activity "confirmar" solo se activa al final de la rutina que contiene la llamada y por lo tanto se ejecutan las instrucciones que siguen a la llamada antes de que se despliegue el formulario que pide la información al usuario.
Alguna explicación a esto?

Comment: Deberías dar más detalles ya que es confusa tu pregunta, como obtienes los datos, un Thread? agrega tu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es muy clara tu pregunta, pero me parece que tu problema es debido a que las instrucciones en la "Activity" se realizan en otro hilo.
Por lo tanto en tu función, se hace la llamada a Confirmar y el hilo continua la ejecución.
Si deseas que el contenido de la actividad se realice y después se haga mas código, tienes que utilizar parámetros de callback, es decir otra función que se ejecutará cuando termine la actividad.
No es posible detener la ejecución para que se realice la actividad y después la misma función continue su ciclo procedural. Tienes que partir esa función en dos. Terminarla al llamar la actividad pero pasando en el parámetro callback el nombre de la función donde continua la ejecución.

Si agregas código será mas fácil darte una solución con código también.

Comment: Es razonable su explicación, intentaré subdividir la función que contiene el lanzamiento de la nueva activity, gracias

Comment: Por otra parte, creo que esta situación no es rara y se presenta comúnmente ya que desplegar un formulario de confirmación o de adquisición de datos complementarios es algo que requerimos en cualquier momento en una app y "el instante" en el cual necesitamos desplegarlo es algo que dicta la lógica y la cronología del problema y que difícilmente podemos diferir o aplazar